# How to design a graph database in this scenario?

Tags: database-design, nosql, graph, neo4j

here is my scenario. I have a **pre-defined data type structure** for books. Just take it as an example for the sake of simplicity. The structure looks like the image below. It's a Labeled Property Graph and the information is self-explained. **This data type structure is fixed**, I cannot change it. I just use it.

[image: DTR Example]

When there is 1 book, let's call it *Harry Potter*, in the system, it might look like below:

[image: DTR 1 book]

So, the book has its own property (ID, Name,...) and also contains a field type `MandatoryData`. By looking at this graph, we can know all information about the book.

The problem happens when I have 2 books in the system, which looks like this:

[image: DTR 2 Books]

In this case, there is another book called *Graph DB*, with those information as highlighted.

The problem of this design is: **we don't know which information belong to which book**. For example, we cannot distinguish the `publishedYear` anymore.

My question is: how to solve or avoid this problem? Should I create 1 `MandatoryData` for each book? Could you propose me any design?

I'm using Neo4j and Cypher. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi.
You said "The problem of this design is: **we don't know which information belong to which book**. For example, we cannot distinguish the `publishedYear` anymore." 
But in the graph model you have nodes and vertexes only. The information in one node does not **belong** to any other node. 
If you want any information to actually **belong** to the node, store it as an attribute in the node.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I create 1 MandatoryData for each book?

Yes.

If you cannot get rid of MandatoryData object, you should have one such object per book.

Otherwise I would simplify the model and move any mandatory attributes to the Book object, which will reduce ne04j database size. Modeling relationships which are always 1:1 is possible, but not optimal. You can improve query performance by keeping the data in one object.